# Caption shortcodes not including caption as attribute

Tags: shortcode, captions, customization

I recently installed the [bonpress](http://demo.wpzoom.com/bonpress/) theme and am having trouble with the captions showing correctly. The more I try to understand how captions are supposed to work in Wordpress, the more I suspect something is not happening right with my installation.

When creating a post and inserting an image with a caption, Wordpress creates the following shortcode:

```
[caption id="attachment_40" align="alignleft" width="1024"]<a href="http://wordpress.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/2012-10-30-11.38.36.jpg"><img class="size-large wp-image-40" title="Torn motorcycle cover" src="http://wordpress.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/2012-10-30-11.38.36-e1351653272372-1024x984.jpg" alt="" width="1024" height="984" /></a> That's what I get for only spending $15 on a motorcycle cover[/caption]
```

As I read through several pages such as [the first example here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) and [the sample code here](http://wp-snippets.com/remove-default-inline-style-of-wp-caption/) (used by bonpress), it appears as though the caption should be passed as an attribute, e.g.:

```
[caption id="attachment_40" align="alignleft" width="1024" caption="That's what I get for only spending $15 on a motorcycle cover"]<a href="http://wordpress.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/2012-10-30-11.38.36.jpg"><img class="size-large wp-image-40" title="Torn motorcycle cover" src="http://wordpress.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/2012-10-30-11.38.36-e1351653272372-1024x984.jpg" alt="" width="1024" height="984" /></a>[/caption]
```

If I manually enter the shortcode with `caption` as an attribute, it renders correctly. Is something broken in my install that makes it so it doesn't build it this way?

**Update:** The caption shortcode is constructed by `image_add_caption` in /wp-admin/includes/media.php (line 134 in WP 3.4.2). The shortcodes are being constructed properly according to this code, so this leaves me wondering why all the code I can find regarding the customization of `img_caption_shortcode` filter assumes the caption is an attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the line `/* Remove [caption] in-line styling` in `function.php`.

Comment out:

```
/*
add_shortcode('wp_caption', 'fixed_img_caption_shortcode');
add_shortcode('caption', 'fixed_img_caption_shortcode');
function fixed_img_caption_shortcode($attr, $content = null) {
    // Allow plugins/themes to override the default caption template.
    $output = apply_filters('img_caption_shortcode', '', $attr, $content);
    if ( $output != '' ) return $output;
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id'=> '',
        'align' => 'alignnone',
        'width' => '',
        'caption' => ''), $attr));
    if ( 1 > (int) $width || empty($caption) )
    return $content;
    if ( $id ) $id = 'id="' . esc_attr($id) . '" ';
    return '<div ' . $id . 'class="wp-caption ' . esc_attr($align)
    . '">'
    . do_shortcode( $content ) . '<p class="wp-caption-text">'
    . $caption . '</p></div>';
}    

*/
```

Find `.entry .wp-caption-text` in `style.css`. Change the style to suite your taste.

Problem fixed. You are done.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: This change applies to the "functions.php" in "\bonpress\functions\theme\functions.php". There is a comment above the code that reads "Remove [caption] in-line styling". This is not what you want to do so the code should be commented out.

Answer (score 0):

I found an imperfect solution on [here](http://queryposts.com/function/img_caption_shortcode/).  Adding the following lines to the theme's `fixed_image_caption_shortcode` function (previously identical to the one [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter)) renders the captions as intended, but doesn't add the caption as an attribute.

```
if ( ! isset( $attr['caption'] ) ) {
    if ( preg_match( '#((?:<a [^>]+>\s*)?<img [^>]+>(?:\s*</a>)?)(.*)#is', $content, $matches ) ) {
        $content = $matches[1];
        $attr['caption'] = trim( $matches[2] );
    }
}
```

This solution is sufficient, but hopefully someone has a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to force the shortcode back to default-- to re-hijack it-- by adding these two lines after that code runs:

```
add_shortcode('wp_caption', 'img_caption_shortcode');
add_shortcode('caption', 'img_caption_shortcode');
```

That should set the shortcode back to [the Core callback](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/media.php#L610) and undo whatever things that `fixed_img_caption_shortcode` broke.